# What is meant by "space" in "respond in the space provided" in IEEE major revision letter?

Tags: journals, paper-submission

Recently, I have received the following comment.

> When submitting your revised manuscript, you will be able to respond to the comments made by the reviewer(s) in the space provided. You can use this space to document any changes you make to the original manuscript.

Furthermore, I have received the original manuscript (in .pdf) as an attachment. The attached manuscript is highlighted with some red color underlined pop-ups messages.

I am having a doubt regarding the space. What is the space the editor is talking about? Is it the space specified in the original manuscript, or do I need to incorporate the same using a new response sheet.

Comment: It sounds like the resubmission form will include a text box where you can write your response.

Comment: Does resubmission form means the space specified as a pop-up in the original manuscript.

Comment: _the comments made by the reviewer(s) in the space provided_ Please specify what's the format of the comment made by the reviewer(s).

Comment: @JessicaB You're probably right. Would you consider expanding the comment into an answer?

Comment: Sounds like a relic from the times when submission were handled on actual paper.

Comment: @scaaahu. Its in .pdf

Comment: Please add the info you provided above into your question. Once you do it, I will retract my close vote as unclear.

Comment: The info you added was put in wrong place. I edited it to make it right. Also, I vote to re-open the question.

Comment: I voted to reopen after your edit, but it is still not very clear what the pop up messages are. I am assuming that the reviews contain some blank space where you can explain in a few words how you addressed each comment.

Comment: This sounds like a question that can easily be answered with a quick email to the editor.

Comment: The format of the referee report doesn't matter. What matters is the format of the re-submission process.